# Error Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: php, mysqli

El error viene de esta línea:

```
if($res->num_rows > 0 && $res != FALSE)
```

La función completa es ésta:

```
function MostrarMovimientos($conexion){
    $this->calcularpag($conexion);
    unset($_POST['BuscarFecha']);
    unset($_POST['BNum']);
    unset($_POST['BuscarLim']);
    unset($_POST['BuscarMov']);
    $enlaceRec = false;

    $l_sup = $this->numer_reg;
    $l_inf = 0; // Si NO recibimos un valor por la variable $page
    if ($this->contar_pagi > 0) { 
        // Si recibimos un valor por la variable $page ejecutamos esta consulta
        $l_inf = $this->pagi;  
    } 

    $res = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT albaran.NumAlbaran,albaran.tipo,albaran.fecha,albaran.nomEmp,albaran.localizacion,albaran.fecha_pagado,solicita.numCont,solicita.empresa,contenedor.estado
     FROM albaran,solicita,contenedor WHERE contenedor.numCont = solicita.numCont and solicita.empresa = contenedor.empresa and albaran.NumAlbaran = solicita.numAlbaran  ORDER BY albaran.fecha DESC LIMIT $l_inf,$l_sup");


    echo "<table class='table table-sm table-hover'>";

    echo "<thead class='p-3 mb-2 bg-primary text-white'>";
        echo "<tr>";
            echo "<th scope='col'>Número de Albaran</th>";
            echo "<th scope='col'>Tipo</th>";
            echo "<th scope='col'>Fecha</th>";
            echo "<th scope='col'>Empresa</th>";
            echo "<th scope='col'>Localización</th>";
            echo "<th scope='col'>Contenedor</th>";
            echo "<th scope='col'>Residuo</th>";
            echo "<th scope='col'>Dias fuera</th>";
            echo "<th scope='col'>Modificar</th>";
            //echo "<th scope='col'></th>";

        echo "</tr>";
    echo "</thead>";

    echo "<tbody>";
    if($res->num_rows > 0 && $res != FALSE) {
        while($a_res =  mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)){
                echo "<tr>";
                    echo "<td>";
                        echo $a_res['NumAlbaran'];
                    echo "</td>";
                    echo "<td>";
                        echo $a_res['tipo'];
                    echo "</td>";
                    echo "<td>";
                        $daux = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d',$a_res['fecha']);

                        echo $daux->format('d-m-Y');
                    echo "</td>";
                    echo "<td>";
                        echo $a_res['nomEmp'];
                    echo "</td>";

                    echo "<td>";
                        echo $a_res['localizacion'];
                    echo "</td>";

                    echo "<td>";
                        echo $a_res['numCont'];
                        echo " ";
                        echo $a_res['empresa'];
                    echo "</td>";

                    //para enlaces de recogida
                    $comp = mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT * FROM enlace WHERE enlace.NRecogida = '".$a_res['NumAlbaran']."' ");
                    if($comp->num_rows > 0){
                        $a_comp =  mysqli_fetch_assoc($comp);
                        $enlaceRec = true;
                    }

                    //recogida, residuo
                    echo "<td>";
                    if(strcasecmp($a_res['tipo'],'entrega') != 0){
                        if($comp->num_rows > 0){
                            //tenemos que sacar el tipo de residuo
                            if($a_comp['residuo'] != null){
                                echo $a_comp['residuo'];
                            }
                            else{
                                echo "vacío";
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else{
                        echo "-";
                    }

                    echo "</td>";



                    echo "<td>";
                        if(strcasecmp($a_res['tipo'],'entrega') == 0){
                            //entrega
                            $comp = mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT * FROM enlace WHERE enlace.NEntrega = '".$a_res['NumAlbaran']."' ");

                            if($comp->num_rows > 0){
                                //tiene algo enlazado sacamos los días
                                $a_comp =  mysqli_fetch_assoc($comp);
                                echo $a_comp['dias'];
                            }
                            else{
                                //no tiene enlace
                                if((strcasecmp($a_res['tipo'],'entrega') == 0) ){
                                    //es entrega y el contenedor está entregado
                                    $intervalo = $this->CalcularIntervalo($a_res['fecha'],$a_res['fecha_pagado']);

                                    if(!is_null($a_res['fecha_pagado']))
                                        echo "pagado ";

                                    if($intervalo >= $this->MAX2 && $intervalo < $this->MAX){
                                        echo "<p style='color:#e1471e'>";
                                        echo $intervalo;
                                        echo "</p>";
                                    }
                                    else{
                                        if($intervalo >= $this->MAX){
                                            echo "<p style='color:red'><strong>";
                                            echo $intervalo;
                                            echo "</strong></p>";
                                        }
                                        else{
                                            echo $intervalo;
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                                else{
                                    //no tiene recogida y es de tipo entrega, y el contenedor está libre -> ERROR
                                    echo "<div class='alert alert-danger'>
                                            <strong> Incongruencias</strong>
                                        </div>";
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        else{
                            if((strcasecmp($a_res['tipo'],'Recogida') == 0)){
                                //tipo recogida                                
                                if($enlaceRec){
                                    //tiene algo enlazado
                                    echo "-";
                                }
                                else{
                                    //no tiene enlace

                                    $intervalo = $this->CalcularIntervalo($a_res['fecha'],$a_res['fecha_pagado']);

                                    if(!is_null($a_res['fecha_pagado']))
                                        echo "pagado ";

                                    if($intervalo >= $this->MAX2 && $intervalo < $this->MAX){
                                        echo "<p style='color:#e1471e'>";
                                        echo $intervalo;
                                        echo "</p>";
                                    }
                                    else{
                                        if($intervalo >= $this->MAX){
                                            echo "<p style='color:red'><strong>";
                                            echo $intervalo;
                                            echo "</strong></p>";
                                        }
                                        else{
                                            echo $intervalo;
                                        }
                                    }
                                }


                            }

                        }

                    echo "</td>";

                    echo "<td>";
                        echo "<a href= 'modules/modificarMovNuevo.php?num=".$a_res['NumAlbaran']."&tipo=".$a_res['tipo']." '><i style='width:5px;'class='fas fa-pencil-alt'></i></a>";
                        //text-decoration:none quitar color azulde hipervinculo
                        echo "<a style= 'margin-left: 30px;text-decoration:none;color:red;' href='./modules/modal.php?numBorrar=".$a_res['NumAlbaran']." '><i style='width:5px;'class='fas fa-eraser'></i></a>";

                    echo "</td>";

                echo "</tr>";
            }
        }
        else{
        echo "<tr><td><div class='alert alert-danger'>
                <strong> No hay lineas </strong>
            </div></td></tr>";
        }

    echo "</tbody>";
    echo "</table>";   
    echo "<p align='center'>$this->pagi_navegacion</p>";    
}
```

Sé que cuando una query falla devuelve `FALSE` y si no, un objeto `mysqli_result` (porque es `SELECT`).

Luego está la opción de hacer:

```
if( is_array($res)) {
    while($a_res =  mysqli_fetch_assoc($res[0])) ...
```

Pero no entiendo muy bien por qué no falla.

Comment: No puedo añadir comentarios, Te lo pongo aqui. <br>
-Tienes la certeza que la 1 query esta bien?<br>
-Prueba a poner la query en una variable ```$consulta```, y haz un ```var_dump()``` de ella. Es correcta?<br>
-Si todo esto esta bien, la conexión, el objeto, es realmente correcto, ataca donde tiene que atacar?<br>
Ya me cuentas. ;)

Comment: Si `$res` contiene un booleano como dice el error significa que la consulta SQL `$res = mysqli_query(...)` falló, devolviendo `false`, por lo que el mensaje de error lo tienes en `mysqli_error($conexion)`. Podría ser por un error sintáctico en el SQL o bien porque `$l_sup` tiene un valor que no es numérico (¿está definido?).

Comment: No se manejar muy bien Stack perdón, ¡Gracias! Se supone que $l_sup tiene un valor numérico , así que probaré a ver qué sale en el mensaje de error, ¡Gracias!

Comment: @Srsole también lo probaré, ¡Gracias!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema viene de comprobar si `$res` vale `false` **DESPUÉS** de intentar hacer uso de una propiedad:

```
if($res->num_rows > 0 && $res != FALSE)
```

Deberías cambiarlo por:

```
if ($res !== false && $res->num_rows > 0)
```

La segunda comprobación no se realizará si la primera falla.

Además, estás intentando hacer uso de una forma errónea para comprobar si fue bien la consulta o no.

En vez de usar:

```
$res = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT albaran.NumAlbaran,albaran.tipo,albaran.fecha,albaran.nomEmp,albaran.localizacion,albaran.fecha_pagado,solicita.numCont,solicita.empresa,contenedor.estado
  FROM albaran,solicita,contenedor WHERE contenedor.numCont = solicita.numCont and solicita.empresa = contenedor.empresa and albaran.NumAlbaran = solicita.numAlbaran  ORDER BY albaran.fecha DESC LIMIT $l_inf,$l_sup");
if (is_array($res)) {
  while($a_res =  mysqli_fetch_assoc($res[0])) ...
}
```

El resultado almacenado en `$res` es el resultado que devuelve [`mysqli_query()`](https://php.net/es/mysqli_query) que sólo puede ser una clase [`mysqli_result`](https://www.php.net/es/class.mysqli-result) o `false` en caso de error. En ningún caso será una matriz que haga cierta la condición del `is_array()`.

De modo que deberías hacer:

```
/* Realizamos la consulta SQL escapando correctamente los datos */
$res = mysqli_query($conexion, "
  SELECT
    albaran.NumAlbaran,
    albaran.tipo,
    albaran.fecha,
    albaran.nomEmp,
    albaran.localizacion,
    albaran.fecha_pagado,
    solicita.numCont,
    solicita.empresa,
    contenedor.estado
  FROM
    albaran,
    solicita,
    contenedor
  WHERE
    contenedor.numCont = solicita.numCont
    AND solicita.empresa = contenedor.empresa
    AND albaran.NumAlbaran = solicita.numAlbaran
  ORDER BY albaran.fecha DESC
  LIMIT "
    . intval($l_inf) . ","
    . intval($l_sup) . "
  "
);
/* Comprobamos si falló la consulta y en ese caso mostramos el error */
if ($res === false) {
  die('Error SQL: ' . mysqli_error($conexion));
}
/* En caso contrario trabajamos con los datos obtenidos */
while($a_res =  mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) ...
```

Comment: ¡Gracias! ¿Entonces num_rows no se puede usar realmente de comprobación, verdad? Por otro lado, ¿Cómo es posible que la gente que ponga lo de is_array le funcione? Es que lo vi, investigando el error, y no entendía muy bien porqué, de todas maneras, gracias, probaré lo que me dices :)

Comment: Monetillo, ¿Me facilitarías el enlace de donde lo usan para comprobarlo? Por otro lado, lo primero que hay que hacer inmediatamente después de hacer una consulta es comprobar que se realizó correctamente como indico en mi respuesta y mostrar el error para que podamos depurar el código, así evitas usar una propiedad o método sobre el valor `false` que provoca el error.

Comment: Por cierto, ¿Solucionaste tu problema? ¿Puedo ayudarte en algo más? ¿Algo de mi respuesta no funciona como debiera? Házmelo saber para corregirlo o ayudarte en lo que pueda.

Comment: ¡Gracias! He hecho : `if ($res === false) {
  die('Error SQL: ' . mysqli_error($conexion));
} ` y me he dado cuenta que era un error de una columna de la base de datos, que justo hace un par de días la cambié y no encontraba la columna, ¡Muchísimas gracias, de verdad!

Comment: Para eso sirve esa comprobación ;) más incluso que para evitar hacer uso de la propiedad. Me alegra haber sido de ayuda.

Comment: sí, la verdad es que te salva de los despistes así, ¡Muchas gracias! marcada queda, ¡Gracias!